# Magento import csv error products

Tags: magento

I m trying to import the products through csv import in Magento, but it throws the following error :

Invalid value in Website column (website does not exists?) in rows: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8

I am using base as website.

Comment: Well...what do you have on the website column?. Add 2 or 2 rows to the question.

Comment: Can you drop a screenshot of your CSV file ?

Answer (score 1):

In your csv file there should be field _product_websites and it should be set to base for each imported product or indicate web-site name you need. Also make sure that your file is saved with UTF-8 encoding.